# apt-get upgrade with exceptions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, update, upgrade

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and have let it get quite out of date with packages that need updating.

There are a couple of packages I don't want to upgrade like tomcat, php etc.. but I am not sure how I can run a blanket apt-get upgrade to upgrade everything except those packages. Most of the documentation and suggestions I can find only explain how to update specific packages, not the other way around..?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is "package pinning" -- essentially, telling apt, "I want to keep this package at this version".  For a simple single-package pin, add this to `/etc/apt/preferences` (or in a new file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d`):

```
Package: tomcat8
Pin: version 8.0.14-1
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Specify the package name you want, and the version you want to pin it to, and make sure the `Pin-Priority` is over 1000.  Then the package will basically never, ever move from its current version.

You can do trickier things, like pinning to a release (`trusty` rather than `trusty-updates`, for example), selecting lots of packages with a glob pattern, and only letting packages update if they're security updates.  See `apt_preferences`(5) for all the gory details.

Comment: In /etc/apt I don't seem to have a "preferences" file to edit. I do however have a (preferences.d) folder. If I put a file in there what do I call it? Thanks

Comment: Per `apt_preferences`(5): "Note that the files in the /etc/apt/preferences.d directory are parsed in alphanumeric ascending order and need to obey the following naming convention: The files have either no or "pref" as filename extension and only contain alphanumeric, hyphen (-), underscore (_) and period (.) characters. Otherwise APT will print a notice that it has ignored a file, unless that file matches a pattern in the Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently configuration list - in which case it will be silently ignored."

Answer (score 1):

> **To hold a package**:
>
> In short: `sudo apt-mark hold <package>`
>
> or
>
> ```
> echo <package> hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
> ```
>
> **To unhold a package**:
>
> In short: `sudo apt-mark unhold <package>`
>
> or
>
> ```
> echo <package> install | sudo dpkg --set-selections
> ```

Ref: [Exclude packages from `apt-get upgrade`](https://askubuntu.com/a/99780)